# Extract the variance-covariance matrix from a plm fixed effects model

Tags: r, plm

I would like to extract the variance-covariance matrix from a simple `plm` fixed effects model. For example:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld")

M1 <- plm(inv ~ lag(inv) + value + capital, index = 'firm',
          data = Grunfeld)
```

The usual `vcov` function gives me:

```
vcov(M1)

              lag(inv)         value       capital
lag(inv)  3.561238e-03 -7.461897e-05 -1.064497e-03
value    -7.461897e-05  9.005814e-05 -1.806683e-05
capital  -1.064497e-03 -1.806683e-05  4.957097e-04
```

`plm`'s `fixef` function only gives:

```
fixef(M1)
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
-286.876375  -97.190009 -209.999074  -53.808241  -59.348086  -34.136422  -34.397967 
      8           9          10 
-65.116699  -54.384488   -6.836448
```

Any help extracting the variance-covariance matrix that includes the fixed effects would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anyway, maybe there is method for the `plm` class, or something strange here because I get different results with you code. For me `vcov(M1)` gives the same result as `M1$vcov` but you result is very different.

Answer (score 1):

Using `names` sometimes is very useful:

```
 names(M1)
[1] "coefficients" "vcov"         "residuals"    "df.residual" 
[5] "formula"      "model"        "args"         "call"        
 M1$vcov
              lag(inv)         value       capital
lag(inv)  1.265321e-03  3.484274e-05 -3.395901e-04
value     3.484274e-05  1.336768e-04 -7.463365e-05
capital  -3.395901e-04 -7.463365e-05  3.662395e-04
```

Comment: Right, the difference I think just has to do with the different methods available in `plm` for finding the covariance matrix. There are the the Beck and Katz, Heteroskedasticity-consistent, and Driscoll and Kraay approaches at least.

My issue is that I would like to find them for the fixed effect parameters as well as the three main covariates.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up your example, do the following to get the standard errors (if that is what you are interested in; it is not the whole variance-covariance matrix):

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld")

M1 <- plm(inv ~ lag(inv) + value + capital, index = 'firm',
          data = Grunfeld)

fix <- fixef(M1)
fix_se <- attr(fix, "se")
fix_se
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
43.453642 25.948160 20.294977 11.245009 12.472005  9.934159 10.554240 11.083221 10.642589  9.164694
```

You can also use the summary function for more info:

```
 summary(fix)
    Estimate Std. Error  t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
1  -286.8764    43.4536  -6.6019 4.059e-11 ***
2   -97.1900    25.9482  -3.7455 0.0001800 ***
3  -209.9991    20.2950 -10.3473 < 2.2e-16 ***
4   -53.8082    11.2450  -4.7851 1.709e-06 ***
5   -59.3481    12.4720  -4.7585 1.950e-06 ***
6   -34.1364     9.9342  -3.4363 0.0005898 ***
7   -34.3980    10.5542  -3.2592 0.0011174 ** 
8   -65.1167    11.0832  -5.8753 4.222e-09 ***
9   -54.3845    10.6426  -5.1101 3.220e-07 ***
10   -6.8364     9.1647  -0.7460 0.4556947
```

Btw, the documentation expains the "se" attribute:

> Value An object of class "fixef". It is a numeric vector containing
>   the fixed effects with attribute se which contains the standard
>   errors. [...]"

Note: You might need the latest development version for that because much has improved there about `fixef`: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=406